# jquery datetimepicker gives 404 not found (.png files) error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'am using [this](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) datetimepicker on my website. My html file includes .js and .css files ;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asts/css/style.css">           
<script type="text/javascript" src="asts/js/modernizr.2.0.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="asts/js/jquery_1.7.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="asts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js" ></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="asts/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="asts/js/jquery.ui.slider.js" ></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="asts/js/gonnasphere.js" ></script>
```

Also, I've imported the css files of custom minified package and datetime-picker-addon by @import url statement. I've also included the css/images folder with necessary icons.

When I click the text field, the jquery ui plugin works correctly. All the functions and ui works. However, firebug gives me the following network errors ;

- NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://subdomain.domain.com/asts/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png
- NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://subdomain.domain.com/asts/css/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png
- NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://subdomain.domain.com/asts/css/images/ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png
- NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://subdomain.domain.com/asts/css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_ffe45c_1x100.png

Can you please help me to prevent getting this error ?

Comment: Use the [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to create the missing files, and put them in the correct directory. Another option is to look for these images in your CSS files, and rename them to the correct ones.

Comment: I've checked the names. The names are exactly same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. It was a folder fault. When I changed the file paths of .png files in the  `jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css` file, it doesn't show any error.

Before I changed, it was ;

```
url(images/ui-bg_inset-soft_50_c9c9c9_1x100.png)
```

After ;

```
url(../images/ui-bg_inset-soft_50_c9c9c9_1x100.png)
```

Comment: Has anybody reported this to the jqueryui folks?

Answer (score 2):

Those are jQueryUI assets, probably used by jquery.ui.slider.js.

Download the slider (+ its dependencies) from http://jqueryui.com/download and you will find the required CSS & images in `\css\<selected-theme>`

Comment: I've already downloaded custom build. I only included datetimepicker & slider. I've included the files in \css\ui-lightness

Comment: If I download those modules I receive those 4 images in the package, are they present in your /asts/css/images ?

Comment: yes they're present. could it be an encoding issue or permission settings ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I need to download the the JQueryUI assets and put the images folder in the stylesheets folder. I was using the .min files and had to switch for the non min one.
It fixed my problem.